# How do I switch process on remote PC during a rdesktop session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, fedora

I use rdesktop to control a windows 10 PC from local Fedora machine. I was supposed to use `Alt+Tab` key to switch process on the windows 10 PC, but it turned out this key binding effected only on local fedora machine, but not worked on the controled windows 10 PC.

Is there a shourcut key binding to switch process running on win 10 PC while remoting it via rdesktop?

Comment: Did you try full screen mode? On windows you also can't use Alt+Tab on the remote machine without full screen

Comment: I'm using full screen mode on remote machine, when I try Alt+Tab, processes on local machine can be switched, not remote machine.@jw_

Comment: “full screen mode on remote machine” full screen is about the RDP window on local machine